# Unit Test: How to mock specific function with jest?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I want to test something inside **render**, but **getLocationParse()** need to recive **location.search**.

```
export default class EstateDetail extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        const parsed = this.getLocationParse();
        ...     
    }

    getLocationParse(){
        const queryString = require('query-string');
        const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
        return parsed;
    }

      render() {...}
}
```

So I tried to mock **getLocationParse** but fail.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
const getLocationParse = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({id:21});

let app = shallow(
    <EstateDetail/>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import { foo } from './example';

jest.mock('./example', () => ({
  ...require.requireActual('./example'),
  foo: jest.fn()
}));

test('foo should be a mock function', () => {
  expect(foo('mocked!')).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mocked!');
});
```

For more information, you can read GH issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Comment: expect(foo('mocked!')).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mocked!'); - could you plean explain how the function 'foo' return this result ?